# ZipArchive::close(): Can't open file: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, nginx

Появилась данная ошибка  "message": "ZipArchive::close(): Can't open file: Permission denied", погуглив выяснил что связана с правами доступа ubuntu , но в работе использую только open server на винде

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: `погуглив выяснил что связана с правами доступа ubuntu` - с правами доступа: да, с ubuntu: нет.

Comment: `но в работе использую только open server на винде` - без разницы Windows, FreeBSD, Linux, MasOS - везде эта ошибка будет одинаковой

Comment: Эта ошибка значит, что у пользователя под которым запущен сервер не хватает прав для доступа к файлу - вот и все. Дайте этому файлу доступ на чтение нужному пользователю и будет вам счастье.